# How to only keep rows where a value in a column appear often enough

Tags: python, pandas

```
a=df.groupby('value').size()
newFrame = pd.DataFrame()

for el in a.keys():
    if a[el] > 300000:
        newFrame = pd.concat([newFrame, df[df.value == el]])
```

I have written this code which does what I want, but is really slow. I only want to keep the rows where the 'value' entry is the same as in 300000 other rows. If it's contained less often than that, I want to drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original filled by counts with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('value')['value'].transform('size') > 300000]
```

If processing output later:

```
df = df[df.groupby('value')['value'].transform('size') > 300000].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `value_counts`

```
df=df.drop(df.value.value_counts().loc[lambda x : x<=300000].index)
```